# Cannot display correct records in unbound form in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have one Table called tblEmployees  - ID, First, Last. One unbound form called frmSearch with a textbox named Searchbox and a search button that searches by ID.I have one more unbound form called frmDisplay that displays the search result in it which I would like to edit when necessary. The textbox fields for this form are EID, Fname, Lname.

The problem I am having is when I enter the ID# in the searchbox and click the search button (where I linked both ID fields in the button wizard) it keeps on displaying  the second record in my table. This is the code I currently have running

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim rst As Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblEmployees WHERE ID=ID")

EID.Value = rst!ID
Fname.Value = rst!First
Lname.Value = rst!Last

end sub
```

When I change the code to read

```
("SELECT * tblEmployees WHERE ID=" & ID")
```

I get a syntax error missing operator in query expression ID="

Answer (score 0):

ID must have some value. Then concatenate ID:

```
"Select * From tblEmployees Where ID = " & ID & ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The recordset that's currently being opened will include all the records in your table, because for every record the condition `ID = ID` will always be true. It's purely coincidence that it's displaying the second record from your table. You didn't specify a sort on the recordset query so it could randomly pick up any record as the first one in the results. What you actually need is

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from tblEmployees WHERE ID = " & frmSearch!Searchbox)
```